# Why is my function not being seen?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting an error while trying to redirect my users based on the selection from a dropdown. I get:

> locationSelect is not defined
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

My `<script>` code is placed in the document's head.
I also tried moving the script inline, before and after the element with no luck.

```js
function locationSelect() {
  var e = document.getElementById("mothersLoc");
  var location = e.value;

  else if (location == "buff") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.place.com";
  } else if (location == "erie") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.place2.com";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mothersLoc" class="form-control" name="location" style="margin: 0 auto;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom: 0px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 300;max-width:260px;margin-bottom: 10px" onchange="locationSelect()" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select a Location</option>
  <option value="erie">Erie, PA</option>
  <option value="buff">Williamsville, NY</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Starting a statement with `else if...` throws an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else`.

Comment: Where did you see the _"locationSelect is not defined"_ error message? The error in @showdev's comment should be above it

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, all you need to do is remove the first "else" in the conditional. This should make sense, considering you have to specify a condition before you can specify what *else* to do if the condition doesn't return true.

```js
function locationSelect() {
  var e = document.getElementById("mothersLoc");
  var location = e.value;

  if (location == "buff") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.place.com";
  } else if (location == "erie") {
    window.location.href = "https://www.place2.com";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mothersLoc" class="form-control" name="location" style="margin: 0 auto;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom: 0px;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 300;max-width:260px;margin-bottom: 10px" onchange="locationSelect()" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select a Location</option>
  <option value="erie">Erie, PA</option>
  <option value="buff">Williamsville, NY</option>
</select>
```